# Scrapy FormRequest not working on credit card login form

Tags: scrapy

I'm unable to get the Scrapy spider to crawl my Discover account page.

I'm new to Scrapy. I've read all the relevant documentation, but can't seem to get the form request to submit correctly. I've added formname, userID, and password.

```
import scrapy

class DiscoverSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Discover"
    start_urls = ['https://www.discover.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname='loginForm',
            formdata={'userID': 'userID', 'password': 'password'},
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
        return
```

After form submission, I expect the spider to crawl my account page. Instead the spider is getting redirected to 'https://portal.discover.com/psv1/notification.html'. The following is the spider console output:

```
2018-12-26 11:39:46 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: 
MoneySpiders)
2018-12-26 11:39:46 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, 
libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, 
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)], 
pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018), cryptography 2.3.1, 
Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
2018-12-26 11:39:46 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: 
{'BOT_NAME': 'MoneySpiders', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'MoneySpiders.spiders', 
'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['MoneySpiders.spiders']}
2018-12-26 11:39:46 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-12-26 11:39:46 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader 
middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-12-26 11:39:46 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-12-26 11:39:47 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-12-26 11:39:47 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-12-26 11:39:47 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 
0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-12-26 11:39:47 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console 
listening on 
2018-12-26 11:39:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
https://www.discover.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-12-26 11:39:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
https://www.discover.com> (referer: None)
2018-12-26 11:39:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
https://portal.discover.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-12-26 11:39:48 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: 
Redirecting (302) to <GET 
https://portal.discover.com/psv1/notification.html> from <POST 
https://portal.discover.com/customersvcs/universalLogin/signin>
2018-12-26 11:39:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
https://portal.discover.com/psv1/notification.html> (referer: 
https://www.discover.com)
2018-12-26 11:39:48 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing 
<GET https://portal.discover.com/psv1/notification.html> (referer: 
https://www.discover.com)
```

Comment: Well, without seeing the content of notification, it's hard to know what is wrong. Have you examined the response content (you'll likely need an `errback=` or to turn on `HTTP_CACHE`)? Further, are you setting the correct user-agent so they don't know you're a Spider?

Answer (score 1):

From the response I got this:

> Your account cannot currently be accessed. Outdated browsers can
>   expose your computer to security risks. To get the best experience on
>   Discover.com, you may need to update your browser to the latest
>   version and try again.

So it looks like the website doesn't recognize your spider as a valid browser. To solve that you will need to set a proper User-Agent and maybe some others headers commonly used by this browsers